# OpenCV CUDA: GpuMat not uploading

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to upload to the GPU using CUDA in OpenCV 3.1:

```
Mat testImg = Mat::zeros(Size(640,480), CV_8UC3);
GpuMat gpuImg = GpuMat(testImg);
```

In a simple program, that works. But I have a huge project, where there two lines can't be excuted, even at the beginning of the main function. I debugged it and got in `gpu_mat.cu` until line 222 `create(mat.size(), mat.type());`:
[Starting at line 213 in gpu_mat.cu] (Full code of this file: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/cuda/gpu_mat.cu)

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////upload

void cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload(InputArray arr) {
    Mat mat = arr.getMat();

    CV_DbgAssert( !mat.empty() );

    create(mat.size(), mat.type()); //programm goes until here; this function does not return; the program just hangs here

    CV_CUDEV_SAFE_CALL( cudaMemcpy2D(data, step, mat.data, mat.step, cols * elemSize(), rows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) ); 
}
```

The value of `rows` of `mat` is 640, the value of `cols` is 480 as it should be. Has someone any solution? I'm nearly falling into despair.

Comment: How much memory does the GPU have? 475,956,122 columns times 640 rows times (a guess) 4 bytes per element is 1.21845e12 bytes ~= 1135 GB ~= 1.1 TB. I know of no GPU that provides more than 24 GB of on-board memory.

Comment: In fact, the Image has 480 cols; I don't know why the value at debugging is that high. In my other test program, where this works, the number of cols is also that high.

Comment: In diagnosing the issue, we can go only by the information that is presented by the asker, which in this case indicates that the allocation requested exceeds the storage capacity for any known GPU and therefore fails. Maybe there is a problem elsewhere in the code that causes this, but without a minimal, buildable and runnable repro code, I don't see how more assistance can be rendered here. Voting to close.